# Filter query from a sqllite3 database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to flask and currently building a microblogging application to learn it. I'm trying to add a feature where a user gets suggestions like "people you should follow ".

Model file:

```
from app import db

followers = db.Table('followers',
db.Column('follower_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
db.Column('followed_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)

class User(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username=db.Column(db.String(32),index=True,unique=True)
    First_name=db.Column(db.String(32))
    Last_name=db.Column(db.String(32))
    password=db.Column(db.String(32))
    email=db.Column(db.String(20))
    posts=db.relationship('Post',backref='author',lazy='dynamic')
    last_seen=db.Column(db.DateTime)
    about_me=db.Column(db.String(200))
    followed=db.relationship('User',
                        secondary='followers',
                        primaryjoin=followers.c.follower_id==id,
                        secondaryjoin=followers.c.followed_id==id,

    backref=db.backref('followers',lazy='dynamic'),
                        lazy='dynamic')

    def follow(self,user):
        if not self.is_following(user):
            self.followed.append(user)
            return self

    def unfollow(self,user):
        if self.is_following(user):
            self.followed.remove(user)
            return self

    def is_following(self,user):
       return `self.followed.filter(followers.c.followed_id==user.id).count()>0`

    def followed_posts(self):
        return `Post.query.join(followers,followers.c.followed_id==Post.user_id).filter(followers.c.follower_id==self.id).order_by(Post.timestamp.desc())`
```

The is_following() function checks if the logged in user is following another user.

Here's the line of code used to return the list of non-followed users.

```
suggested_users=User.query.filter(g.user.is_following(User) is False).order_by(func.random()).limit(2).all()
```

All the users follow themselves. The problem is that suggested_users always evaluates to an empty list.
can someone help?
g.user is set to current_user.

Comment: Are your function supposed to be in your class. Right now they are not

Comment: actually it is inside the class.made a mistake while formatting. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Why do you have back ticks in your return statements.